# Combine query results into a single row and display time span?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

First, I apologize for not having a fiddle, but my data set was too large. So I am [including a file](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=CCBE197DAD50B153&id=ccbe197dad50b153%21134).

I have a set of queries that combine user data with location data. The location history data is gathered from RF devices and a history for that user is persisted. Going against the supplied [SQL file](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=CCBE197DAD50B153&id=ccbe197dad50b153%21134) I need to combine the data where a Staff member may enter a room, leave that room, then come back. This example may constitute a visit with a patient. Another example is if a Staff member is logged in a room consecutively. We are only concerned with data where the time stamps are greater than 2 minutes in length. Meaning the RF reader may read a tag if a staff member walks by a room and that location is logged. Here are the intial set of queries:

```
with 

StaffHistory as(
SELECT
LocationHistories.UserProfileId,
UserProfiles.FirstName,
UserProfiles.LastName,
LocationHistories.LocationId,
Locations.LocationName,
LocationHistories.LocationHistoryTimeStamp,
PreviousLocationTime = LAG(LocationHistories.LocationHistoryTimeStamp, 1) OVER 
  (PARTITION BY LocationHistories.UserProfileId ORDER BY LocationHistories.LocationHistoryTimeStamp),
NextLocationTime = Lead(LocationHistories.LocationHistoryTimeStamp, 1) OVER 
  (PARTITION BY LocationHistories.UserProfileId ORDER BY LocationHistories.LocationHistoryTimeStamp)
FROM
LocationHistories
INNER JOIN UserProfiles ON LocationHistories.UserProfileId = UserProfiles.Id
INNER JOIN Locations ON LocationHistories.LocationId = Locations.Id
where LocationTrackingType = 1),

StaffInRoomTime as(
SELECT
StaffHistory.UserProfileId,
StaffHistory.FirstName,
StaffHistory.LastName,
StaffHistory.LocationId,
StaffHistory.LocationName,
DATEDIFF(SECOND, LocationHistoryTimeStamp, NextLocationTime) as TimeSpentInRoom,
StaffHistory.LocationHistoryTimeStamp,
StaffHistory.PreviousLocationTime,
StaffHistory.NextLocationTime

FROM
StaffHistory
Where DATEDIFF(SECOND, LocationHistoryTimeStamp, NextLocationTime) > 120
)

select * from StaffInRoomTime ORDER BY UserProfileId, LocationHistoryTimeStamp
```

I used common table expressions just for this example. These are actual views in the DB.

The first query joins the histories with the staff. We also create a couple columns for the Previous logged time and the Next logged time. This is so we can determine the length of time in a room.

The second query pulls from the first query and we set a column for how long the staff member was in that location during that time and we also filter any data out where the `LocationHistoryTimeStamp` and `NextLocationTime` are greater than 2 minutes.

What I am trying to achieve is combine the data where a staff member may be logged for a room consecutively or if they leave the room and come back.

Here is an example of the data set where the Staff member is in a room consecutively for:
[image]

Here would be the outcome:
[image]

Here is an example of spanning multiple rooms for a given visit:
[image]

I have tried using a `Inner Join` on the second query that uses the `Min(LocationHistoryTimeStamp)`. However, the time spans ended up not being correct so I am missing something.

This was the Inner Join query I tried:

```
 Select
    StaffHistory.LocationId, 
    StaffHistory.LocationName, 
    StaffHistory.UserProfileId,
    Min(LocationHistoryTimeStamp) as LocationHistoryTimeStamp,

    DATEDIFF(SECOND, Min(LocationHistoryTimeStamp), Lead(Min(LocationHistoryTimeStamp), 1) OVER 
      (PARTITION BY UserProfileId ORDER BY Min(LocationHistoryTimeStamp))) As TimeSpentInRoom,

    NextLocationTime = Lead(Min(LocationHistoryTimeStamp), 1) OVER 
      (PARTITION BY UserProfileId ORDER BY Min(LocationHistoryTimeStamp))
    FROM
    StaffHistory 
    Where TimeSpentInRoom > 120
    GROUP BY LocationId,LocationName,UserProfileId
```

Comment: What would be the output for Glen for example? Can you add complete otput for Glen as it should be in final result?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, I updated the results for Dr. Glen

Comment: Is that picture a final result that you want to get or it is the result that you get now but is incorrect? I want correct final result.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, i apologize, I thought you wanted to see the full set. I included the projected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is statement:

```
WITH    StaffHistory
          AS ( SELECT   LocationHistories.UserProfileId ,
                        UserProfiles.FirstName ,
                        UserProfiles.LastName ,
                        LocationHistories.LocationId ,
                        Locations.LocationName ,
                        LocationHistories.LocationHistoryTimeStamp ,
                        PreviousLocationTime = LAG(LocationHistories.LocationHistoryTimeStamp,
                                                   1) OVER ( PARTITION BY LocationHistories.UserProfileId ORDER BY LocationHistories.LocationHistoryTimeStamp ) ,
                        NextLocationTime = LEAD(LocationHistories.LocationHistoryTimeStamp,
                                                1) OVER ( PARTITION BY LocationHistories.UserProfileId ORDER BY LocationHistories.LocationHistoryTimeStamp )
               FROM     LocationHistories
                        INNER JOIN UserProfiles ON LocationHistories.UserProfileId = UserProfiles.Id
                        INNER JOIN Locations ON LocationHistories.LocationId = Locations.Id
               WHERE    LocationTrackingType = 1
             ),
        StaffInRoomTime
          AS ( SELECT   StaffHistory.UserProfileId ,
                        StaffHistory.FirstName ,
                        StaffHistory.LastName ,
                        StaffHistory.LocationId ,
                        StaffHistory.LocationName ,
                        DATEDIFF(SECOND, LocationHistoryTimeStamp,
                                 NextLocationTime) AS TimeSpentInRoom ,
                        StaffHistory.LocationHistoryTimeStamp ,
                        StaffHistory.PreviousLocationTime ,
                        StaffHistory.NextLocationTime
               FROM     StaffHistory
               WHERE    DATEDIFF(SECOND, LocationHistoryTimeStamp,
                                 NextLocationTime) > 120
             ),
        prepareIsland
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        CASE WHEN LAG(LocationId) OVER ( PARTITION BY UserProfileId ORDER BY LocationHistoryTimeStamp ) <> LocationId
                             THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END AS prepIsland
               FROM     StaffInRoomTime
             ),
        islands
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        SUM(prepIsland) OVER ( ORDER BY UserProfileId , LocationHistoryTimeStamp ) AS Island
               FROM     prepareIsland
             )
    SELECT  island ,
            UserProfileId ,
            FirstName ,
            LastName ,
            LocationId ,
            LocationName ,
            SUM(TimeSpentInRoom) TimeSpentInRoom ,
            MIN(LocationHistoryTimeStamp) LocationHistoryTimeStamp ,
            MIN(PreviousLocationTime) PreviousLocationTime ,
            MAX(NextLocationTime) NextLocationTime
    FROM    islands
    GROUP BY island ,
            UserProfileId ,
            FirstName ,
            LastName ,
            LocationId ,
            LocationName
    ORDER BY UserProfileId ,
            LocationHistoryTimeStamp
```

Comment: So basically we are grouping by the occurrence a given staff member is in a room. I was thinking of it in terms of time rather than location.

Comment: Yes you just capture the change between rows and mark it as 1, then sum makes the islands